# c# blazor Can't pass "i" into function, any other way?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to pass "i" as a parameter on @onclick="()=>ButtonToggle(i)", that seems to not work, is there an intended way to do it?
Like store the "i" as element id and then referencing the id in "ButtonToggle(ElementIdReference)"?

Note: I know it can be done with components, I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible that's why im not using them in this case.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        <button  style='@(ChosenKanas[i] == true ? "background-color: hotpink;" : "")' @onclick="()=>ButtonToggle(i)"  >@MainHiraganas[0,0]/@MainHiraganas[i,0]</button>
        
    }
```

Comment: `style=$'@(ChosenKanas[{i}] == true ? "background-color: hotpink;" : "")'` Does this do anything?

Comment: It changes the background if the boolean that the button represents is true (i could have done this with a checkbox probably), the equivalent would be:
if (ChosenKanas[i] == true) { background-color: hotpink } else { background-color: white }

Comment: Create a new local variable in the loop `var j=i; ..... @onclick="()=>ButtonToggle(j)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "closing over the loop variable".

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    int iCopy = i; 
    <button  style='@(ChosenKanas[i] == true ? "background-color: hotpink;" : "")' 
       @onclick="()=>ButtonToggle(iCopy)">
       @MainHiraganas[0,0]/@MainHiraganas[i,0]</button>        
}
```

the `iCopy` is needed on the right side of the `=>`